# GoogleTokenResponse does not contain ID token, intermittently

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-play-games, google-authentication

Intermittently, GoogleTokenResponse.parseIdToken() has an NullPointerExpection because the token response does not contain an ID token.  Without changing any code, sometimes there is an ID token, and sometimes there isn't.  Note that GoogleTokenResponse.getAccessToken() always works.

With no change to any code whatsoever, the ID token will be missing from one minute to the next, even if the access token is always available.

How can I debug this?  Where to look?

I get the server auth code using this in an Android client using Google Play Games API:

```
PendingResult<Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult> pendingResult =
                    Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(mGoogleApiClient, Constants.web_client_ID);
            pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult getTokenResult) {    
                    sendToServer(getTokenResult.getCode());
                }
            });
```

On the server side (Google Cloud Endpoints), I exchange the code for a token using this code:

```
try {
     tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    transport,mJFactory,
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                    web_client_ID,web_client_secret,
                    authCode,
                    "")
                    .execute();
        } ...
        String accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
        GoogleIdToken idToken = null;
        try {
            idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken();  //-- FAILES HERE INTERMITTENTLY!!!!
        } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that Play Games Services does not guarantee an ID token using `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode` one should follow the directions in this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) and get the ID token as it recommends:

> Once you have the access token, you can now call
>   www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications//verify/ using that
>   access token. Pass the auth token in a header as follows:
>   “Authorization: OAuth ” The response value will contain
>   the player ID for the user.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510996/getting-google-play-games-player-id-on-server) for a full example.